# Marking function as function in TypeScript type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to declare type for components props as shown below:

```
type TSPaymentFormProps = {
  paymentAmountType: string,
  totalAmount: number,
  prolongationAmount: number,
  currentProcListInfo: object,
  customAmount: number,
  invalidAmount: boolean,
  handleAmountChange: any,
  setPaymentType: function
}
```

The last one should be labeled as function but I am getting error `cannot find name 'function'`. How do I do it?

Comment: Functions have parameters and a return type. `setPaymentType: (param1:string, param2:number) => void` -- fill in your actual parameters and types.

Comment: Also `Function` is a type in TS that accepts any function. However, in general, it shouldn't be used *because* it accepts any function, rather than ones with signatures you expect.

Comment: `setPaymentType: (paymentType: PaymentType) => void`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions

Answer (score 2):

To define a type as a function in TypeScript we use `Function` something like this `setPaymentType: Function` which generalize it to any function and not the best approach. To specify the function type in more details it's parameter types and return type are defined like this `setPaymentType: (param1: <Param Type>, param2: <Param Type>) => <Return Type>` and if the function does not have any param and doesn't return anything we can write it as `setPaymentType: () => void`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this  `setPaymentType: () => void`